What is the correct way to verify pdal plugins (.e57 reader) in OSGeo4W shell?
When running the command pdal info "Z:\myE57pointcloud.e57" --summary
inside the  OSGeo4W (Windows) shell, I receive the error:

PDAL: Couldn't create reader stage of type 'readers.e57'.
You probably have a version of PDAL that didn't come with a plugin
you're trying to load.  Please see the FAQ at https://pdal.io/faq.html

When I run the same command inside conda shell with pdal installed, it runs fine and returns the summary.
I have went into the OSGeo shell setup and reinstalled pdal and pdal-plugins but there is no change.  How can I verify the install is ok and if not what is the correct method to run this with OSGeo4W?

I do not believe that you can get the PDAL e57 reader into OSGeo4W. The installed readers can be listed from the OSGeo4W shell with a command pdal --drivers and readers.e57 is not on the list. The PDAL project recommends to use conda https://pdal.io/en/2.6.0/download.html#windows. See also https://github.com/PDAL/PDAL/issues/3130 that says that if you are not happy with conda then you can compile PDAL yourself.
The OSGeo4W build script for PDAL is at https://github.com/jef-n/OSGeo4W/blob/master/src/pdal/osgeo4w/package.sh and I do not find anything about e57 there.

Yes, conda PDAL works fine.

You could try filing a ticket at https://trac.osgeo.org/osgeo4w/ to get it added. It just requires libxml2 which is already available in OSGeo4W and setting the switch to turn on the plugin.
